# Separability degree of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{3})/\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, separable-extension

I want to find $[L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}, \sqrt[3]{3}):K=\mathbb{Q}]_s$.

In lecture I learned that for every algebraic closure $\iota_a:K\rightarrow K^a$ it's true that...

\begin{align*}
[L:K]_s = \#\{\text{different roots of } \iota^*_a (m_x)\}
\end{align*}
where $\iota^*_a:K[X]\rightarrow K^a[X]$ and $m_x$ is the minimal polynomial for $x$. I took $K^a = \mathbb{A}$ (field of all algebraic numbers)

I have for
\begin{align*}
&m_{\sqrt{2}} = X^2-2 =(X-\sqrt{2})(X+\sqrt{2}) \quad \text{ and } \\
&m_{\sqrt[3]{3}} = X^3-3 = (X-\sqrt[3]{3})(X-\sqrt[3]{3}\cdot e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}})(X-\sqrt[3]{3}\cdot e^{\frac{4\pi i}{3}})
\end{align*}

These roots are different from each other and are all in $\mathbb{A}$. Therefore,

\begin{align*}
[L:K]_s =[L:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]_s \cdot [\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}):K]_s = 3\cdot 2 = 6
\end{align*}

Am I correct?

Comment: Extensions in characteristic zero are always separable, so the separable degree is always the same as the usual degree. Inseparability is a purely positive characteristic phenomenon.

Comment: By the way, you don't specify what field the minimal polynomial is taken over. It is unclear if you are looking at the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt[3]{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, or over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$ (they are the same, but you never say it explicitly so it is not clear, and it won't always be the same for arbitrary extensions of the form $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha,\beta)$...)

Comment: @ArturoMagidin it's the minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Then your computation is incorrect: the separable degree $[L:\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})]_s$ would not be the number of roots of the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, it would be the number of roots of the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt[3]{3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Do you see why?